# Li elements in navbar don't fill the available space of navbar

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I make a hybrid mobile app with PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.
I made a footer navbar, and my problem is that the list elements of the navbar don't fill the available space of the navbar, only the 4th list element, the other 3 is shorter a bit, and remains a little white line at the bottom of the navbar. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
 <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-custom-navbar">
  <ul id="navbarul">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="img/lips.png" /><p>thing_1</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="img/lips.png" /><p>thing_2</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="img/lips.png" /><p>thing_3</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="img/lips.png" /><p>thing_4</p></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem hasn't appeared until I had put for the images the max-width: 100%; property in the CSS file, because without it the images would be too large.
Here is the CSS code:

```
.ui-custom-navbar a {
     background-color: #3BA6D2 !important;
}

.ui-custom-navbar a:hover{
     background-color: #317996 !important;
}

.ui-custom-navbar p {
     color: #ffffff !important;
     text-shadow: none;
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     text-align: center;
}

.ui-grid-c > .ui-block-a, .ui-grid-c > .ui-block-b, .ui-grid-c > .ui-block-c, .ui-grid-c > .ui-block-d {
     max-height: 6em !important;
}

.ui-block-a .ui-btn-active, .ui-block-b .ui-btn-active, .ui-block-c .ui-btn-active, .ui-block-d .ui-btn-active{
     border-color: #ffffff !important;
}

#navbarul li img{
     border: 0;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

The result is here on the picture: [image](http://tinypic.com/r/2mh7w49/8)

What would be the solution?
Thank you for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM has a CSS rule that applies a negative right margin to the last ui-btn in the navbar. You can override it by adding this CSS:

```
.ui-navbar li:last-child .ui-btn {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/t2zgsz5u/)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried your code, but with the same result. Here is a picture about my problem: [link](http://i61.tinypic.com/2mh7w49.jpg)

Comment: Try changing the CSS rule to #navbarul li .ui-btn { margin-right: 0 !important;}. It definietly solves the issue in the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/t2zgsz5u/1/